# OSError in one of the threads of Bottle framework, while running the dev server

Tags: python, multithreading, bottle

When I run bottle development server, I notice some warning showing up.
Can any one figure it out what exactly is the problem?

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 525, in __bootstrap_inner
   self.run()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/bottle-0.8.1-py2.6.egg/bottle.py", line 1406, in run
   if path: files[path] = mtime(path)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/bottle-0.8.1-py2.6.egg/bottle.py", line 1401, in <lambda>
   mtime = lambda path: os.stat(path).st_mtime
OSError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/github2-0.1.2-py2.6.egg/github2/issues.py'
```

Comment: Which version of bottle? Can you show your code?

Comment: We are using 0.8 bottle version.I am sorry, I can't disclose the code.

Comment: This error does not come when running the application through apache. It only comes when we run the bottle development server, also we are using github api. Is github is an issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in bottle (solved in 0.8.2). The reloading feature checks for modified module files and is confused by paths that point into egg archives. Update to 0.8.2 or disable the reloading-feature to solve this.